# How can display function list of a javascript file in Vs 2012 Express for Web?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012

You know, the function list can be displayed in Class view window when I edit a .cs file in Vs 2012 Express for Web, just like the following image.

Now I hope the function list can be displayed when I edit javascript file, how can I set in Vs 2012 Express for Web ? Thanks!

[image]